# C multiple pthread call to function in another file and store a value to the variable in there as global

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a main `main.c` that create multiple thread with same function.

I'm using pj_thread_t from PJSUA API as the thread.

then I separate the pjsua api function in different file let's say `pjsua.c`. So I can call it from the thread in main.

in the `pjsua.c`,

- there is a global variable, let's say `int index_room_number`
- there is a a function to call room using pjsip call function, let's say `void * make_call(int* index_of_room)`
- in the pjsua api, there is a callback function to detect the current call state, so there is a function `static void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e)`

in `main.h`,

I store every room number in a

```
#define MAX 260
struct Room {
    int         number;
    char*       guest;
    time_t      wake;
    unsigned int    in_queue    : 1;
    unsigned int    is_called   : 1;
    unsigned int    call_count  : 2;
    unsigned int    status;
};
extern struct Room room[MAX];
```

for every room need to be called in the main thread, I create a new thread, and than call the `make_call` function passing the `index_of_room`. In that function `make_call`, I access the room[index_of_room].number and call the sip extensions.

The `on_call_state` function will be automatically print the `status_code` if the call is confirmed, or rejected.

The problem is, I need somehow to update the `room[index_of_room].status` from `on_call_state`, but the `index_of_room` value is exist only in the function `make_call`. So I store the `index_of_room` in the global variable of `index_room_number` in order to expose the value to the `on_call_state`.

Then another problem appear, that is, the `index_room_number` being overwritten by every thread that call the function `make_call` because the variable is shared between all thread. So I need the global variable that could appear in all of the function in `pjsua.c`, but will contain different value for every thread that call that function.

How to achieve something like that. I'm still new to C Programming, so I couldn't figure out the correct way to do it.
If in OOP, maybe that file can be analogous as a class.

Comment: Extern the variable, put a mutex on it to make sure it's synchronized across all threads.

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Aha, regarding your edit - you *could* achieve something like that using `Thread Local Storage` aka `TLS` or simply by letting all of those threads having a few private variables which need to be thread-specific. But thread-local storage can't be visible everywhere, and ... i'm out of good ideas. Perhaps you could abuse `variable shadowing` to achieve the use-case you're after.

Comment: Another edit might be in order, because - `If in OOP, maybe that file can be analogous as a class. ` how would your use-case translate to OOP? Static variables (to be able to be visible everywhere) but with different values for different threads? I'm not quite getting the idea behind your proposed implementation...

Comment: @Shark if in OOP, i would create Room Class, and PJSUA Wrapper, set the variable as `Room` instead of int with non-static. an instantiate the object in the thread. and pass the Room Object in the `make_call` function, and assign it to the variable. But how to make non-static variable in C?

Comment: @Hendrik isn't that very close to what `the only answer so far` suggests? C can work in those ("OOP") ways too, think of a struct as a class as it too can have private methods, there's no big theoretical difference between the two. The practical difference is that you can see the struct clearly in-memory while a class instance is just mangled text. Everything else can be pretty much retained.

Comment: btw Thanks @Shark, I'll try to search about `Thread Local Storage` for more information.

Comment: @Shark, Could you give me a link to tutorial about OOP in C? I'm still couldn't really grasp it in C. The environtment I use is for server with OS Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to pass the variable around everywhere it is needed.

To make the solution extendable (adding more variables with minimal work), put the variable in a `struct`:

```
typedef struct myContext {
    int intVar;
    char *stringVar;
} MyContext;
```

Then you add a `MyContext*` parameter to all functions that need access to the threads global variables.

Example of usage:

```
int foo(MyContext* context, int param1, int param2) {
    if (context->intVar == 0) {
         // Do something special
    } 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately, this technique doesn't work with 3rd party callback architectures since you cannot change the function signatures.

In callback architectures you are usually supplied with some kind of identifier in the callback. If you associate the identifier with the struct and store the structs in a collection (array, linked list, map, whatever is best suited for the task) you can then use the identifier to retrieve the right struct. Note that manipulation of the collecton must be protected from concurrent usage, for example by a mutex.

In your case, in your `make_call` function you would associate the call id with a room number.
In your callback you can look up the association and get the right struct.
When the call ends, or is dropped, you remove the association.

Comment: thanks for your response @Klas, but I still couldn't figure it out how to implement it in my case. Am I need to change the whole program flow and use different approach? But I don't know how the different approach is.